# Jest toEqual is failing and I don't know why

Tags: jestjs

I'm running the tests for a package I'd like to help contribute to. However, when running the tests, which I'd assume should work, I'm getting a myriad of failing tests with this kind of output.

```
 ● PagingType › should create the correct filter graphql schema

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 20
    + Received  + 20

    - type Query {
    + type Query {
    -   test(input: Paging!): Int!
    +   test(input: Paging!): Int!
    - }
    -
    + }
    +
    - input Paging {
    + input Paging {
    -   """Paginate before opaque cursor"""
    +   """Paginate before opaque cursor"""
    -   before: ConnectionCursor
    -
    +   before: ConnectionCursor
    +
    -   """Paginate after opaque cursor"""
    +   """Paginate after opaque cursor"""
    -   after: ConnectionCursor
    -
    +   after: ConnectionCursor
    +
    -   """Paginate first"""
    +   """Paginate first"""
    -   first: Int
    -
    +   first: Int
    +
    -   """Paginate last"""
    +   """Paginate last"""
    -   last: Int
    +   last: Int
    - }
    -
    + }
    +
    - """Cursor for paging through collections"""
    + """Cursor for paging through collections"""
    - scalar ConnectionCursor
    + scalar ConnectionCursor
      ↵

      22 |   const sf = await getOrCreateSchemaFactory();
      23 |   const schema = await sf.create(resolvers);
    > 24 |   return expect(printSchema(schema)).toEqual(sdl);
         |                                      ^
      25 | };
      26 |
      27 | export const aggregateArgsTypeSDL = readGraphql(resolve(__dirname, './aggregate-args-type.graphql'));

      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.expectSDL (packages/query-graphql/__tests__/__fixtures__/index.ts:24:38)
```

It seems like "toEqual" just isn't working correctly, because there seems to be nothing actually wrong between the two text outputs.

This is another set of example outputs of a console.log of the strings being compared. The failures are also happening with objects too.

```
type Query {
        updateTest(input: UpdateOne!): Int!
      }

      input UpdateOne {
        """The id of the record to update"""
        id: ID!

        """The update to apply."""
        update: FakeUpdateOneType!
      }

      input FakeUpdateOneType {
        name: String!
      }

type Query {
        updateTest(input: UpdateOne!): Int!
      }

      input UpdateOne {
        """The id of the record to update"""
        id: ID!

        """The update to apply."""
        update: FakeUpdateOneType!
      }

      input FakeUpdateOneType {
        name: String!
      }
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong/is happening?

Comment: R u comaping two objects?

Comment: Sometimes an object, sometimes text. Whenever it's toEqual, it fails.

Comment: please share ur two objects/texts, update in your question, let me check

Comment: Added. Not sure how that will help. Both strings are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. As it seems, it's a Windows/ Git issue.

This is the text with `JSON.stringify`

```
console.log
      "type Query {\n  updateTest(input: UpdateOne!): Int!\n}\n\ninput UpdateOne {\n  \"\"\"The id of the record to update\"\"\"\n  id: ID!\n\n  \"\"\"The update to apply.\"\"\"\n  update: FakeUpdateOneType!\n}\n\ninput FakeUpdateOneType {\n  name: String!\n}\n"

      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.expectSDL (packages/query-graphql/__tests__/__fixtures__/index.ts:22:11)

    console.log
      "type Query {\r\n  updateTest(input: UpdateOne!): Int!\r\n}\r\n\r\ninput UpdateOne {\r\n  \"\"\"The id of the record to update\"\"\"\r\n  id: ID!\r\n\r\n  \"\"\"The update to apply.\"\"\"\r\n  update: FakeUpdateOneType!\r\n}\r\n\r\ninput FakeUpdateOneType {\r\n  name: String!\r\n}\r\n"
```

If Git for Windows isn't set up correctly, it will add `/r/n` as line breaks when cloning a repo. If the project was developed in anything other than Windows, then text comparisons with `toEqual` that have line breaks in them will fail. Too bad Jest doesn't say something like "mismatched line breaks" or show the escaped characters.

To fix this, I installed Git for Windows (I needed to upgrade anyway) with this option, which sets core.autocrlf to "input".

[image]